# Apache POI and XMLConstants Conflict

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, stax, javax

After adding the **org.apache.poi** ***poi-ooxml*** dependency to my project, I am now getting the following error:

> javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI cannot be resolved or is not a field

When I try to view the source, there no longer is one, and eclipse is looking for the source in: *.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1-sources.jar*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**poi-ooxml** also imports **stax-api**, which contains a custom version of **javax.xml.XMLConstants**.

My solution was to have Maven exclude this import in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>stax</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi can you please help me out, I am trying this `compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'{
        exclude group: 'stax', name:'stax-api'
    }` and it is showing error as `Error:(64, 0) Could not find method org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17()`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had this issue while switching from jdk 1.7 to jdk 1.8,the compiler used stax's version of XMLConstants instead of the standard one.